# Open a workbook while a code is running on another one

Tags: vba, excel

My question is basically the title...

I have a workbook opened with a macro running inside.
When I try to open another workbook during the process it loads forever.

**Question :** If I have a macro running in a workbook, is there a way to open another workbook ?

Regarding the code which is running, I ensured using the *ThisWorkbook* denomination so that it wouldn't be altered by the opening of other workbooks.

For your information my code is :

```
Option Explicit
Private objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Sub MySub()
'i)Declaration of the variables
    Dim i As Integer           
    Dim Path As String ' stores the path

'ii)Path to the platform
    Path = "https://www.mywebsite.com"
 '1)Navigate to the platform
        Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        objIE.Visible = True
        objIE.navigate Path
    Do
    Loop While objIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    '3)Check Price
Start:

    Do
    Loop While CLng(objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("Myclassname")(0).innerText) > 4200 And CLng(objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("Myclassname")(0).innerText) < 4500
   '4) Write down the value in Excel
    i = i + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(7 + i, 4) = CLng(objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("Myclassname")(0).innerText) ' Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(7 + i, 3) = Right(Now, 8) ' Time
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(7 + i, 2) = Date ' Date
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
    GoTo Start

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to open the other workbook so you can get on with something else while the code runs, or the code needs the other workbook to be open as part of its process?

Comment: No the other workbook I'd like to open has nothing to do with the one which has the code running in. So yes, it's to get on with something else exactly.

Comment: Open another instance of Excel and open your new workbook in that.  I tried it with an endless loop activating each sheet in a workbook and didn't affect the other Excel in any way I could see.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't work for me. I cannot open any other Excel files, because it loads forever. I have Windows 7 by the way.
See my code in the update if it can help.

Comment: Try adding DoEvents within the loop and see if that helps...

Comment: Yep, `DoEvents` might help.  When you say you can't open other Excel files - you have opened another instance of the Excel _application_ to open these other files in first?

Comment: @Felphal : Great thanks. With this little extra bit I the VBA editor window and Excel one don't freeze. I didn't know the `DoEvents` had this impact

@DarrenBartrup-Cook : Now, I understand what you meant. Yes, if from the start I open each worbooks (including the one in which I want to run the code) from an instance rather than the fiel itself, it WORKS :) Thanks a lot

I learned 2 things in one post, great value !